# How can i remove some file from fineuploader before upload

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader with multiple file upload, which works great. Now I ran some MD5 checks in the submit event, so I can determine if the file is already uploaded, but I don't know how to remove this files from the upload query or `storedFiles` before manually triggered upload.
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#uploader").fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: 'home/upload'
        },
        multiple: true, 
        autoUpload: false,                                      
        editFilename: {                                            
            enable: true
        }
    }).on({                                                      
        "complete": function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) { 
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                alert("upload success");
            }
        },

        "submit": function (event,id, fileName) {             
            var f=$(this).fineUploader('getFile',id);
            var xxxx = CheckMD5(f, id);
            if (xxxx==false) {               //i want ignore the file if checkMD5 return false
                $(this).fineUploader.cancle(id) //this is not working

            }


        },

        "error": function (event, id, fileName, reason) {      
            //alert(reason);
        }
    });


    $("#uploadButton").click(function () {                         
        $('#uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
    function CheckMD5(f,id) { //i'm using spark-md5.js get to get md5 value and compare in server side
        return false; //this is for test
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My answer details two ways to handle this, please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a file (before it has started or completed uploading), simply cancel it via the [`cancel` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#cancel).

For example:

```
callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id) {
        if (fileIsInvalid) {
            this.cancel(id);
        }
    }
}
```

A better way to do this, in my opinion, is to test files in an [`onValidate` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validate), and simply return false  (or return a promise and reject/resolve it when your  async validation operation is done) to omit the file.

Comment: thanks,the onValidate callback worked!